# Concurrency pattern: worker with variable number of results

Tags: go, design-patterns, concurrency

I want to create a worker pool in golang, to divide a big task in multiple jobs.

The problem is that the routines may produce multiple output as a result for the computation, so I cannot know in advance how many times I shall iterate over the results channel.

I know that I can use WaitGroup, but I was wondering if there is another pattern I can use, in order to let the main thread advanced on the computation and iterate over the results instead of waiting first every routine to be done.

Another solution I thought, which is not very elegant to me, is to create a `Result` struct or return an array of results. Since I can count the number of works, I know how many results arrays I'm gonna receive.

Comment: The main thread (or whatever thread is reading the results) can read the results from the results channel while processing is ongoing, it doesn't have to wait for all the workers to finish to start handling results.

Comment: Yes, but at some point it has to stop. How can I know when all workers are done working?

Comment: You know they're done by using a waitgroup. But you can use the waitgroup to choose when to *stop* looking for results rather than when to *start*.

Comment: It's looks like a cleaver solution, but I've just checked the docs and there is now way to query the value of the Wg. Maybe I shall using something like an AtomicInteger? Thank you in the mean time :)

Comment: Why would you need to query the value? Presumably you don't want to stop reading results until all the workers are finished, which is exactly what Done() is for.

Comment: Because `Done()` is a blocking call - I would do something like `while wg.value > 0: receiveResults()`. Maybe you can add an answer with a small example so I can also accept it?

Comment: You iterate (range) over channel until it is closed, so no need to know in advance how many items it contains.

Comment: `for i:= range chan` is a blocking call. It goes on until someone don't close the channel. And it should be closed by the thread who created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
}()

for res := range results {
    // Handle results
}
```

When all your workers finish processing, close the results channel. The process that's reading results will finish and then exit the loop.

Comment: that's great! Thank you very much